# Prove that G contains an element $a$ of row $71$. (G is a non-Abelian group of order $142$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be a non-Abelian group of order $142$. Prove that G contains an element $a$ of row $71$.
I know how to prove that G contains an element if it is of an even order. What about the odd?

Comment: We have no idea what you mean by 'row' here. It's not standard terminology. Please explain further if you want responses.

Comment: For example: Row of a group means the number of elements in a group.

Comment: Oh. The standard term is 'order'. So "G is a ... group of order 142", and "G contains an element of order 71" would be the way to say it. (Hope I don't seem mean. I'm sure your English is better than my use of any non-English language.)

Comment: No, it is not mean at all. Thank you for correcting me! Sometimes you learn the things the hard way. haha

Comment: Is there a group that order of it's $142$ and non-Abelian? We may work on an empty set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** By Lagrange Theorem, every element has order 1,2,71 or 142.

If there is an element of order 71 you are done. If there is an element of order 142, then you are done (why?).

Otherwise, every element has order 1 or 2. Prove that in this case $G$ is abelian.

Comment: And in the "otherwise" case you can even prove that $G$ has cardinal a power of $2$

Comment: @Max Yes, BUT the prove would involve some heavier results in group theory, while the suggested approach is a problem I typically put on the very first assignment in an undergraduate group theory course ;)

Comment: Yeah I know I was just mentioning it, because I think it's an interesting result ^^

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.By Lagrange's theorem every elements has order that decide 142 i.e the order of the group.Look there can't be any element of order 142(if it occurs then G is cyclic and hence abelian).If every elements has order 2 then each of them are self-inverse.which implies G is abelian.Hence you see that G must have one element of order 72.